# the best way to increment a letter n times

Tags: php

I have a variable with upper case letter (eg: `$var = 'C'`) when I increment it, it becomes next letter in alphabet (eg: `echo ++$var //gives D`). Now I want to increment this letter 10 times. If I do `$var += 10`, it becomes `10`. I know that this is possible to perform with the `for` loop, but it seems very unproductive. Is there a better way to do it?
**Edit:**
How is the actual letter incrementation logic works? Does it somehow moves bytes or something else? I guess there should be a better way than using the loop.
*P.S.:*
If I increment `Z` it would become `AA`. I need the same.

Comment: @George, that answer is not what I am looking for. I am searching for best practise, what is written there I have found out myself

Comment: *Is there a better way to do it?* -- Nope.

Comment: @George there are 1000000 of programmers out there, maybe someone had a better solution. I think you should reopen the question!

Comment: I haven't closed the question (I don't have the power to do so alone..). This is still open to answers.

Comment: I am disapointed there was no reason to mark it as duplicated. Stackoverflow gets full of negative users.

Comment: We aren't being negative, we are trying to point you in the right direction. OK so the question might not be a duplicate, but the top answer there should give you an idea of why you can't do what you are trying.

Comment: @George Please, read the title. I am not asking the way how to increment the letter `n` times using `++`. I am asking the best way to achieve the same logic. This is different.

Comment: Inorder you need to post your attempts what you have tried so far to achieve such functionality at your own

Comment: @NarendraSisodia I have described what I have tried, but when you have no idea about what to do next, you cannot try anything.

Comment: @zazu Check my updated answer. Does it fulfill your requirements

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `for` loop then you can simply use `range` as

```
$arr = 'C';
$result = array_map(function($a)use(&$arr){return $arr++;},range(1,255));
print_r($result);
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](https://eval.in/420260)

Comment: It ends with `Z` and does not continue.

Comment: It all depends on user dependency

Comment: @zazu Which letter comes after Z?

Comment: I think OP is been interested in something like `ZA` @CharlotteDunois

Comment: @CharlotteDunois @NarendraSisodia that is `AA`

Comment: Dont you think this would take too much memory? For example I need to increment the letter 500 times, it is going to create array with 500 elements I think it would lead to memory leak :)

Comment: @zazu [Check This](https://eval.in/420271)

Comment: @NarendraSisodia hmm dunno, I was expecting some kind of calculation which would generate expected string. Anyway thanks, if I wont be able to solve the problem in better ways I would mark it as correct. I generated the approximate solution in my mind. I just thought I would be given better suggestions here :)

Comment: [Check This](https://eval.in/420306) its better to use `foreach` loop instead of `array_map`